# jquery generate different id for each keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-collision

Good day all, I'm trying to make a space shooting game using jquery and jquery-collision. I'm almost done finishing but one problem is, everytime I press `spacebar` to shoot it only creates same ID & class of `projectile` divs. So if the 1st `projectile` is being shot on a blank side & another one is being shot towards the enemy, after hit both of them disappear at the same time. Here are the codes:

```
function spawnBullet() { 
$("#content").append($("<div />")
.attr('id', 'projectile1')
.addClass("projectile")
.css({ "left" :  $('#fighter').offset().left + 25, 'top' : $('#fighter').offset().top - 20 })); 
}

function processBullet() {
$(".projectile").each(function() {
    var maxTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var breakable = $(".projectile").collision( "#boss" );
    //console.log(maxTop);
    $(this).css("top", maxTop - 3);
    if (maxTop <= 110 || breakable.length != 0) {
      $('#projectile1').remove();
      $("#score").html(++score);
    }

    if (breakable.length != 0) {
       breakable.remove();
       sound.play();
       spawnEnemy();
     }
});
}
setInterval(processBullet, 50);

function shoot() {
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
switch (event.keyCode) {
case 32:
    spawnBullet();
    break;
}
});
}
```

I want to create different id based divs for each `spawnBullet()` call. But I can't come up with any ideas. Need help desperately. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure how some of these things work and this may be way off.  You loop through every projectile using

```
$(".projectile").each(function() {...})
```

During each iteration you test if any of the bullets collided using

```
var breakable = $(".projectile").collision( "#boss" );
```

Would it not make sense to just test the bullet that is being iterated?

```
var breakable = $(this).collision( "#boss" );
```

and then

```
if (maxTop <= 110 || breakable.length != 0) {
  $(this).remove();
```

The benefit is that you don't need ids at all.

Comment: omg this worked like a charm. Tnx a lot bro. Though I need id because I'm going to use different bullets for different upgrades. Anyways, tnx again. U r simply genius!

Answer (score 2):

You can create unique ids by just maintaining a global counter that you increment each time and then append that number onto the end of whatever root name you want to use.

For example:

```
var idCntr = 0;

function spawnBullet() { 
    $("#content").append($("<div />")
        .attr('id', 'projectile' + idCntr++)
        .addClass("projectile")
        .css({ "left" :  $('#fighter').offset().left + 25, 'top' : $('#fighter').offset().top - 20 })); 
}
```

If you don't want to create a new global variable or want to protect it from tampering, you can put it in a closure:

```
var spawnBullet = (function() {
    var idCntr = 0;

    return function () { 
        $("#content").append($("<div />")
            .attr('id', 'projectile' + idCntr++)
            .addClass("projectile")
            .css({ "left" :  $('#fighter').offset().left + 25, 'top' : $('#fighter').offset().top - 20 })); 
    }
})();
```

---

In other cases, the current time (in ms) serves as a unique enough id though you have to be careful if using this multiple times in a tight loop because you may get the same time value that way, but you won't get the same time value if you use it once per user event:

```
        .attr('id', 'projectile' + new Date().getTime())
```

---

If you're not saving this id somewhere, I might ask why you even need it?

Comment: smart enought for a jquery shooting-game but demn counters are hard

Comment: @jfriend00, i tried your code. Its working but now a new problem rise. Even if I manage to create different ID based divs, how am I gonna remove only those when they collide with the enemy divs. & for ur last ques, I only need it because I already told in my question `projectile` divs are removing themselves all at a same time even if  only one hit the enemy.